# Null-forgiving operator results in nullable type

Tags: c#, .net-core

I've a .NET 6.0 C# console project with the property `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`. In it, I've the following, where `Span` is a primitive data type:

```
sealed class PrivateParser {
   private void FatalError(int msgId, Span span /*, ...*/) {
       /* ... */
   }
}
```

When I call `FatalError()`, immediately forgiving null in the second agument:

```
FatalError(0x80A0400, id.Span!);
```

The compiler outputs:

```
error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from
'ShockBasic.Semantics.SourceData.Span?' to
'ShockBasic.Semantics.SourceData.Span' [C:\Users\hando\Documents\shockbasic\sb\ShockBasic.Compiler.csproj]
```

See [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving), the operator should return the non-nullable type, thus I'm a bit lost.

To reproduce it, the full project is in this [GitHub commit](https://github.com/shockbasic/sb/commit/6b523b9998f49beec2d556b865da99644e8a5dca). Run `dotnet build` and you can look at the last error. Locations

- [Span](https://github.com/shockbasic/sb/blob/6b523b9998f49beec2d556b865da99644e8a5dca/src/ShockBasic.Semantics/SourceData/Span.cs)
- [PrivateParser](https://github.com/shockbasic/sb/blob/6b523b9998f49beec2d556b865da99644e8a5dca/src/ShockBasic.Syntax/Parser.cs#L50)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) that you have added in the question:

> you use the null-forgiving operator to declare that expression x of a **reference** type isn't null.

`Span` is a value type. To change "Nullable value type" (in your case (`Nullable<Span>`/`Span?`) To non nullable, when calling the method you should use `FatalError(0x80A0400, id.Span.Value);`, but that may throw `InvalidOperationException` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types#examination-of-an-instance-of-a-nullable-value-type)) when the `id.Span` will be null

Comment: I didn't pay attention to that part, thanks a lot!